# How to fetch private key from Chrome Web Store

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension

I added application to Chrome Web Store using this tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish. It is not published yet. I needed application ID in order to generate client ID to make Google Drive working. Now I would like to create crx file and send it for beta tests. To generate crx with the same ID I need private key. So far as I know in the scenario in which I uploaded zip file to CWS private key is generated by CWS. The question is how to export this private key from CWS?? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's information on how to do this here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging

You can't ever get a pem file once it's gone. Essentially what happened is you let the chrome publish api generate the pem. You should delete what's in the store, and follow the packaging information to generate your own pem and set the key in your manifest file before publishing.

Comment: I see information that private key is generated during first crx package creation only. But after installing this crx app has different ID in extensions. I do not see information how to get private key from Chrome Web Store for extension which was already uploaded to CWS. Could you tell more details?

Comment: You can't ever get a pem file once it's gone.  Essentially what happened is you let the chrome publish api generate the pem.  You should delete what's in the store, and follow the packaging information to generate your own pem and set the key in your manifest file before publishing.

Comment: How can I remove what is in store? I cannot see any "delete" button?? I am reading that removing products is not possible. Is there any workaround??

Comment: I think you can just unpublish it from the web store. There used to be a way, but I am seeing inconsistent answers as well, and I haven't done it myself in a while.